# Is this normal GC behaviour from support.map.fragment?

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-maps-v2

I'm having some issues understanding the GC, and Maps V2. On Zoom (in / out) the GC kicks in constantly cleaning up, making the application hang for half a second in the mapview.

If I remove the mapview from the application everything runs fine, but as soon as I add the mapview GC kicks brutal in (On create, and on zoom in /out).

I'm using the supportv4.support.map.fragment. I dont know if I should include layout and code? As this is many classes, and a whole lot of code for a general question.

Would you say this is my fault / Most likely implemented maps wrong? Or caused a memory leak?
Or is this normal behavior? I run the app on my Xperia Z, and it works "ok", but if I try it on my S2 it's a nightmare.

**A print of my Logcat going wild :**

```
08-18 00:57:27.759: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4796K, 61% free 21315K/54640K, paused 34ms, total 35ms
08-18 00:57:29.681: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5994K, 61% free 21580K/54640K, paused 5ms+5ms, total 53ms
08-18 00:57:29.681: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 36ms
08-18 00:57:32.433: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3498K, 61% free 21699K/54640K, paused 67ms, total 67ms
08-18 00:57:32.804: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4774K, 61% free 21723K/54640K, paused 33ms, total 34ms
08-18 00:57:32.904: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5096K, 62% free 20916K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:57:33.224: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5296K, 62% free 20997K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 33ms
08-18 00:57:33.344: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5301K, 62% free 21083K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:57:33.454: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5397K, 63% free 20667K/54640K, paused 35ms, total 36ms
08-18 00:57:33.725: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4481K, 60% free 22222K/54640K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 37ms
08-18 00:57:33.825: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6110K, 61% free 21595K/54640K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
08-18 00:57:33.915: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5407K, 59% free 22492K/54640K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 38ms
08-18 00:57:33.915: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 26ms
08-18 00:57:33.915: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 29ms
08-18 00:57:33.995: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4654K, 60% free 22322K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:57:34.155: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5992K, 59% free 22815K/54640K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 34ms
08-18 00:57:34.155: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 28ms
08-18 00:57:34.155: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 26ms
08-18 00:57:34.275: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5334K, 58% free 23396K/54640K, paused 33ms, total 40ms
08-18 00:57:34.415: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5573K, 58% free 23322K/54640K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
08-18 00:57:34.505: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4165K, 58% free 23277K/54640K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
08-18 00:57:34.636: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4192K, 58% free 23238K/54640K, paused 41ms, total 42ms
08-18 00:57:34.736: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4138K, 58% free 23217K/54640K, paused 37ms, total 37ms
08-18 00:57:34.886: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5108K, 56% free 24575K/54640K, paused 46ms, total 46ms
08-18 00:57:35.026: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6540K, 56% free 24073K/54640K, paused 51ms, total 52ms
08-18 00:57:35.156: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4840K, 55% free 24738K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:57:35.356: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4325K, 55% free 24635K/54640K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
08-18 00:57:35.436: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4122K, 55% free 24632K/54640K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
08-18 00:57:35.526: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4722K, 57% free 24029K/54640K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
08-18 00:57:35.597: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4233K, 57% free 23916K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:57:36.027: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4581K, 57% free 23750K/54640K, paused 34ms, total 35ms
08-18 00:57:36.117: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4297K, 57% free 23573K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 33ms
08-18 00:57:36.207: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4223K, 58% free 23467K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:57:36.277: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4184K, 58% free 23399K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:57:36.357: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4209K, 58% free 23305K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:57:36.447: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4252K, 58% free 23173K/54640K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
08-18 00:57:36.988: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4669K, 58% free 23038K/54640K, paused 35ms, total 36ms
08-18 00:57:37.508: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4589K, 59% free 22919K/54640K, paused 54ms, total 55ms
08-18 00:57:38.940: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6052K, 57% free 23609K/54640K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 71ms
08-18 00:57:38.940: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 41ms
08-18 00:57:38.940: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 26ms
08-18 00:57:39.250: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6227K, 58% free 23000K/54640K, paused 33ms, total 34ms
08-18 00:57:40.501: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6455K, 58% free 23360K/54640K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 77ms
08-18 00:57:40.501: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 57ms
08-18 00:57:40.822: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 7158K, 58% free 23100K/54640K, paused 2ms+5ms, total 38ms
08-18 00:57:40.822: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 23ms
08-18 00:57:41.022: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2905K, 57% free 23771K/54640K, paused 37ms, total 38ms
08-18 00:57:41.122: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6499K, 56% free 24292K/54640K, paused 7ms+6ms, total 44ms
08-18 00:57:41.122: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 36ms
08-18 00:57:41.232: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5791K, 57% free 23732K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:57:41.322: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4391K, 57% free 23723K/54640K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
08-18 00:57:41.402: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4853K, 58% free 22986K/54640K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
08-18 00:57:41.472: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4111K, 58% free 22975K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:57:41.602: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6093K, 57% free 23652K/54640K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 46ms
08-18 00:57:41.602: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 27ms
08-18 00:57:41.602: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
08-18 00:57:41.702: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5077K, 57% free 23645K/54640K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
08-18 00:57:41.783: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4265K, 57% free 23495K/54640K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
08-18 00:57:41.993: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4500K, 58% free 23113K/54640K, paused 81ms, total 81ms
08-18 00:57:42.083: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4842K, 60% free 22385K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:57:42.824: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4872K, 60% free 22271K/54640K, paused 41ms, total 41ms
08-18 00:57:42.934: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4732K, 60% free 22288K/54640K, paused 50ms, total 50ms
08-18 00:57:49.941: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5747K, 62% free 21152K/54640K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
08-18 00:57:50.081: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4324K, 62% free 20956K/54640K, paused 36ms, total 36ms
08-18 00:57:50.221: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4134K, 62% free 20925K/54640K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
08-18 00:57:52.193: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5892K, 62% free 21133K/54640K, paused 4ms+8ms, total 51ms
08-18 00:57:52.193: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 33ms
08-18 00:57:52.283: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1769K, 60% free 22065K/54640K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
08-18 00:57:52.353: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4917K, 61% free 21594K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:57:52.443: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5029K, 63% free 20683K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:57:52.523: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4289K, 63% free 20512K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:57:52.603: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4141K, 63% free 20486K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:57:52.723: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4425K, 62% free 20829K/54640K, paused 29ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:57:53.064: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5106K, 62% free 20810K/54640K, paused 40ms, total 41ms
08-18 00:57:56.347: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6009K, 62% free 20820K/54640K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 80ms
08-18 00:57:56.497: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2729K, 62% free 20880K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:57:56.597: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4888K, 63% free 20374K/54640K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
08-18 00:57:56.937: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5928K, 64% free 20162K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:57:57.077: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 4630K, 61% free 21408K/54640K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 37ms
08-18 00:57:57.077: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 30ms
08-18 00:57:57.077: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
08-18 00:57:57.077: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 30ms
08-18 00:57:57.238: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6073K, 62% free 20893K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:57:57.318: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4142K, 62% free 20868K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:57:57.818: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4675K, 62% free 20893K/54640K, paused 34ms, total 35ms
08-18 00:57:57.898: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4127K, 62% free 20884K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:57:57.968: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4208K, 62% free 20798K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:57:58.179: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5894K, 63% free 20313K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:57:58.919: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5791K, 63% free 20421K/54640K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 40ms
08-18 00:57:58.919: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 35ms
08-18 00:57:59.079: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5360K, 63% free 20334K/54640K, paused 33ms, total 34ms
08-18 00:57:59.300: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5742K, 63% free 20509K/54640K, paused 3ms+14ms, total 119ms
08-18 00:57:59.310: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 12ms
08-18 00:57:59.690: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2021K, 61% free 21445K/54640K, paused 42ms, total 44ms
08-18 00:57:59.830: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5660K, 60% free 21941K/54640K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
08-18 00:57:59.930: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5045K, 60% free 22231K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:58:00.040: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4584K, 60% free 22140K/54640K, paused 54ms, total 54ms
08-18 00:58:00.130: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4670K, 61% free 21591K/54640K, paused 34ms, total 35ms
08-18 00:58:00.221: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4148K, 61% free 21562K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:58:00.321: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4164K, 61% free 21519K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:58:00.401: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4217K, 61% free 21417K/54640K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
08-18 00:58:00.471: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4105K, 61% free 21416K/54640K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
08-18 00:58:00.611: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4794K, 61% free 21371K/54640K, paused 33ms, total 34ms
08-18 00:58:00.681: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4107K, 61% free 21370K/54640K, paused 29ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:58:02.393: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5465K, 61% free 21435K/54640K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
08-18 00:58:02.523: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4571K, 59% free 22563K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:58:03.614: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 6525K, 61% free 21447K/54640K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
08-18 00:58:03.724: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4316K, 61% free 21581K/54640K, paused 42ms, total 42ms
08-18 00:58:05.015: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5834K, 60% free 21992K/54640K, paused 3ms+6ms, total 43ms
08-18 00:58:06.056: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6081K, 60% free 22291K/54640K, paused 3ms+7ms, total 43ms
08-18 00:58:06.056: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 29ms
08-18 00:58:06.677: D/dalvikvm(12809): JIT code cache reset in 1 ms (1048524 bytes 2/0)
08-18 00:58:06.687: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 7111K, 61% free 21744K/54640K, paused 3ms+7ms, total 55ms
08-18 00:58:06.687: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 19ms
08-18 00:58:08.278: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4619K, 60% free 22283K/54640K, paused 45ms, total 45ms
08-18 00:58:08.389: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5813K, 59% free 22471K/54640K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
08-18 00:58:08.469: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4225K, 60% free 22366K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:58:08.549: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4363K, 60% free 22122K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:58:08.789: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5598K, 60% free 21959K/54640K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
08-18 00:58:08.869: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4264K, 61% free 21812K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:58:08.949: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4332K, 61% free 21595K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:58:09.019: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4344K, 61% free 21371K/54640K, paused 29ms, total 29ms
08-18 00:58:09.109: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4273K, 62% free 21234K/54640K, paused 29ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:58:09.349: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5486K, 61% free 21376K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:58:09.450: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4512K, 61% free 21369K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:58:10.270: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4973K, 61% free 21620K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 33ms
08-18 00:58:10.370: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4236K, 61% free 21641K/54640K, paused 34ms, total 34ms
08-18 00:58:10.471: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4620K, 61% free 21365K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:58:10.541: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4108K, 61% free 21365K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:58:12.232: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5405K, 61% free 21615K/54640K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
08-18 00:58:12.382: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5083K, 59% free 22860K/54640K, paused 4ms+5ms, total 40ms
08-18 00:58:12.382: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
08-18 00:58:12.382: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 2ms
08-18 00:58:12.472: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4242K, 59% free 22790K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:58:12.553: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4204K, 59% free 22702K/54640K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:58:13.113: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5858K, 59% free 22847K/54640K, paused 37ms, total 38ms
08-18 00:58:13.223: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4548K, 59% free 22712K/54640K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
08-18 00:58:13.323: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4339K, 59% free 22625K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:58:13.413: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5406K, 61% free 21599K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:58:13.604: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 6158K, 61% free 21733K/54640K, paused 2ms+4ms, total 38ms
08-18 00:58:13.614: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 32ms
08-18 00:58:15.005: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4289K, 59% free 22877K/54640K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
08-18 00:58:15.095: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4504K, 59% free 22520K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:58:15.175: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4684K, 60% free 21950K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:58:15.245: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4162K, 60% free 21904K/54640K, paused 29ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:58:16.176: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5225K, 58% free 23043K/54640K, paused 3ms+7ms, total 64ms
08-18 00:58:16.276: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4773K, 57% free 23539K/54640K, paused 33ms, total 33ms
08-18 00:58:16.376: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4421K, 57% free 23510K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:58:16.456: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4215K, 58% free 23474K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:58:16.827: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5377K, 59% free 22494K/54640K, paused 38ms, total 39ms
08-18 00:58:16.917: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4138K, 59% free 22476K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 32ms
08-18 00:58:16.987: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4263K, 60% free 22324K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:58:18.909: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5483K, 60% free 22387K/54640K, paused 33ms, total 34ms
08-18 00:58:19.009: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4107K, 60% free 22382K/54640K, paused 39ms, total 39ms
08-18 00:58:19.119: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4455K, 60% free 22348K/54640K, paused 35ms, total 35ms
08-18 00:58:21.902: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7009K, 61% free 21810K/54640K, paused 38ms, total 38ms
08-18 00:58:22.112: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5015K, 58% free 23221K/54640K, paused 3ms+4ms, total 38ms
08-18 00:58:22.112: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 28ms
08-18 00:58:22.112: D/dalvikvm(12809): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 30ms
08-18 00:58:22.232: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5467K, 60% free 22264K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
08-18 00:58:22.302: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4119K, 60% free 22264K/54640K, paused 31ms, total 31ms
08-18 00:58:22.372: D/dalvikvm(12809): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4100K, 60% free 22263K/54640K, paused 30ms, total 30ms
```

Comment: Is e.g. Google Maps showing the same? Freeing 5MB multiple times a second seems much but there are also lots of images that need to be loaded and unloaded while you zoom.

Comment: GC is not as active in Gmaps as in my app, but it consumes more memory, and the GC_concurrent / GC_FOR_ALLOC also appears in gmaps. But not as frequently as in my app. (Tho overall performance is not that different). EDIT : The GC does not cause lagg in the gmaps, but does create spikes of lagg in my app.

Comment: I think some of your codes need to be modified. I could only see things like this in my own app is because I have done something wrong and the whole app is frozen. The s2 situation that you say is what I describe with 'the whole app is frozen'. You should first clean your project and build it again. Also if it is ok, I suggest you to remove you app from your phone first. Sometimes the data between two different versions of your app also cause this problem.